# Smarty-Function-Variable outside the function

Tags: php, function, templates, variables, smarty

ich have a smarty-function in my template, into which the variable *myvar* is passed..

```
{function name="myfunction" myvar=""}

{/function}
```

the variable is filled inside the function, and I need to output this variable outside the function.. how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you assign the variable inside smarty you can add 'scope=global' param like:

```
{assign var="name" value="Bob" scope="global"}
```

If you only want the variable to be accessed in the current document you can use

```
{assign var="name" value="Bob" scope="parent"}
```

Please see
http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.assign.tpl